# Two Transaction in single time in magento

Tags: magento2, database

I need to save data in 2 tables at once in a single transaction in magento. The value to be stored in table 2 is dependent on values stored in table 1. How to handle this scenario in a single transaction?

Comment: is this for magento 1.9 or magento 2?

Comment: it is for magento2